# How to extract and modify the last field of the uptime command output with sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I need to extract the last field of the `uptime` command, but I also need to remove the `.` that is present. For example, if  the output of `uptime` is

```
19:54:09 up  1:41,  1 user,  load average: 0.32, 0.37, 0.31
```

I need `031`.
I know how to do it using pipe of `awk` and `sed` like this:

```
uptime | awk '{ print $NF }' | sed 's/\.//'
```

Is there any way to do it using **only one** of those two? Can they both do it without the other?

Comment: Whether it is a dot or a comma depends on the language settings of your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just awk:

```
$ uptime | awk '{sub(/\./,"",$NF);print $NF}'
036
```

or get it from the source:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\./,"",$3);print $3}' /proc/loadavg 
034
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
uptime | awk -F'[. ]' '{print $(NF-1) $NF}'
```

***2nd solution:*** With `sed` approach:

```
uptime | sed 's/.* //;s/\.//'
```